# Vuex, what is the best practice for asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm discovering Vuex at this time and I have came across the concepts of `Actions` which should be used instead of `Mutations` if it is about asynchronous code.

But, I have this question, would it better to make all the asynchronous logic in the action itself or do the asynchronous login in the component and just commit `Mutations` in the `then` call?

In other words, is this code considered best practice in the Vuex realm or I just need to move the API call to a state `Action`?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the driving concepts of Vuex and state management systems in general is that the view (Vue) is a relatively simple representation of the current state. When events occur in the view, those events are dispatched to the state management system, which handles the business logic and changes the state.

The standard best practice in this case would be to move the API call into an action.